# Changing Platform settings in Elastic Beanstalk using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to change the platform settings of my application environment in Elastic Beanstalk using AWS CLI.

To be precise I want to change the JVM Options so that I can pass different parameters to the application at different times.

Thank you!

Comment: why not to use env vars?

Comment: @NeverBe Do env vars take precedence over JVM Options if they're both defined?